# Split budget column by total number of months to give average monthly budget

Tags: pandas, group-by, split, average

I am trying to create a new column that has the average monthly budget based on the duration of a campaign

My current data set looks like this

| Client | Start Date | End Date | Campaign | Total Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/01/2024 | 31/01/2024 | 123 | 1,000 |
| DEF | 01/01/2024 | 31/03/2024 | 456 | 15,000 |
| XYZ | 01/01/2024 | 30/06/2024 | 789 | 60,000 |

What I would like to do is to equally divide the Total Budget column for each line based on the duration of the start/end dates

- Row 1: 1 month
- Row 2: 3 months
- Row 3: 6 months
- etc

I'm not sure where to begin with trying to code this so I was wondering if this was even possible to do?

My expected result would be the below

| Client | Start Date | End Date | Campaign | Total Budget | Avg Monthly Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/01/2024 | 31/01/2024 | 123 | 1,000 | 1,000 |
| DEF | 01/01/2024 | 31/03/2024 | 456 | 15,000 | 3,000 |
| XYZ | 01/01/2024 | 30/06/2024 | 789 | 60,000 | 10,000 |

Answer (score 1):

1. If the dates are in datetime format, you can subtract them, which will generate a timedelta.
2. From that you can get the number of days and calculate the corresponding number of months.
3. Then just divide the Total Budget by the number of months.

```py
# optional: convert dates to datetime if they aren't already
df["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

df["Avg Monthly Budget"] = df["Total Budget"] / (
    (df["End Date"] - df["Start Date"]).dt.days // 30
)
```

Result:

```
  Client Start Date   End Date  Campaign  Total Budget  Avg Monthly Budget
0    ABC 2024-01-01 2024-01-31       123          1000              1000.0
1    DEF 2024-01-01 2024-03-31       456         15000              5000.0
2    XYZ 2024-01-01 2024-06-30       789         60000             10000.0
```

Comment: Thanks @e-motta - however, this has caused a couple of issues. February has 29 days this year and not all dates in the start / end date columns are a full month. For example they could be from 15//01/2024 to 31/01/2024.  In these scenarios pandas is returning 'inf' Any ideas?

Comment: That can be fixed, but it depends on the results you're expecting to get. For instance, if the period is 15/01/2024 to 31/01/2024, should the average just be the Total Budget, or something like `Total Budget / (17/31)`? What happens when the range is for instance 45-days long?

Comment: thanks @e-motta. I believe I have fixed it. I should have perhaps been more specific. I only needed the difference between the months, i.e. Jan-Jan is 1 month, Jan-Jun is 6 months. So I created duplicates of my date columns and returned the month value only - pd.to_datetime(planned['start_date1'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.month and then created a calculation similar to the one you provided to work out the duration. There might be a better way of doing it but this seems to be working